# How to implement animated javascript background in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to do an animated background like https://benscott.dev uses. I cannot even seem to find the self closing tags for his canvas elements so I'm honestly not sure what I need to accomplish what he has done here. I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, I just can't seem to find it. I have bootstrap implemented, is it causing the problem?

```js
const canvasDotsBg = function () {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas-2'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    colorDot = [
      'rgb(81, 162, 233)',
      'rgb(81, 162, 233)',
      'rgb(81, 162, 233)',
      'rgb(255, 77, 90)',
    ], // 75% of dots are blue. 25% pink
    color = 'rgb(81, 162, 233)';

  // ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
  canvas.width = document.body.scrollWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.style.display = 'block';
  // ctx.fillStyle = colorDot;
  // ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 50%, 50%)';
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.3;
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;

  let mousePosition = {
    x: (30 * canvas.width) / 100,
    y: (30 * canvas.height) / 100,
  };

  const windowSize = window.innerWidth;
  let dots;

  if (windowSize > 1600) {
    dots = {
      nb: 100,
      distance: 0,
      d_radius: 0,
      array: [],
    };
  } else if (windowSize > 1300) {
    dots = {
      nb: 75,
      distance: 0,
      d_radius: 0,
      array: [],
    };
  } else if (windowSize > 1100) {
    dots = {
      nb: 50,
      distance: 0,
      d_radius: 0,
      array: [],
    };
  } else if (windowSize > 800) {
    dots = {
      nb: 1,
      distance: 0,
      d_radius: 0,
      array: [],
    };
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0;
  } else if (windowSize > 600) {
    dots = {
      nb: 1,
      distance: 0,
      d_radius: 0,
      array: [],
    };

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0;
  } else {
    dots = {
      nb: 1,
      distance: 0,
      d_radius: 0,
      array: [],
    };

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0;
  }

  // decided to turn off connecting dots under 1100px

  // } else if (windowSize > 650) {
  //   dots = {
  //     nb: 400,
  //     distance: 50,
  //     d_radius: 185,
  //     array: [],
  //   };
  // } else if (windowSize > 500) {
  //   dots = {
  //     nb: 325,
  //     distance: 45,
  //     d_radius: 170,
  //     array: [],
  //   };
  // } else {
  //   dots = {
  //     nb: 270,
  //     distance: 45,
  //     d_radius: 140,
  //     array: [],
  //   };
  // }

  function Dot() {
    this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;

    this.vx = -0.5 + Math.random();
    this.vy = -0.5 + Math.random();

    this.radius = Math.random() * 1.5;

    // this.colour = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 50%, 50%)';
    this.colour = colorDot[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorDot.length)];
  }

  Dot.prototype = {
    create: function () {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      // ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;

      // meed to acount for scroll height since the bg is static and uses mouse position
      const top =
        (window.pageYOffset || document.scrollTop) - (document.clientTop || 0);

      // make the dot colour fade out the further they are from the mouse

      const dotDistance =
        ((this.x - mousePosition.x) ** 2 +
          (this.y - mousePosition.y + top) ** 2) **
        0.5;
      const distanceRatio = dotDistance / (windowSize / 2);

      // this chops the bracket off the rgb colour and ads an opacity
      ctx.fillStyle = this.colour.slice(0, -1) + `,${1 - distanceRatio})`;
      // ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;

      ctx.fill();
    },

    animate: function () {
      // dont animate the first dot, it will follow mouse
      for (let i = 1; i < dots.nb; i++) {
        const dot = dots.array[i];

        if (dot.y < 0 || dot.y > canvas.height) {
          dot.vx = dot.vx;
          dot.vy = -dot.vy;
        } else if (dot.x < 0 || dot.x > canvas.width) {
          dot.vx = -dot.vx;
          dot.vy = dot.vy;
        }
        dot.x += dot.vx;
        dot.y += dot.vy;
      }
    },

    line: function () {
      for (let i = 0; i < dots.nb; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < dots.nb; j++) {
          const i_dot = dots.array[i];
          const j_dot = dots.array[j];

          if (
            i_dot.x - j_dot.x < dots.distance &&
            i_dot.y - j_dot.y < dots.distance &&
            i_dot.x - j_dot.x > -dots.distance &&
            i_dot.y - j_dot.y > -dots.distance
          ) {
            if (
              i_dot.x - mousePosition.x < dots.d_radius &&
              i_dot.y - mousePosition.y < dots.d_radius &&
              i_dot.x - mousePosition.x > -dots.d_radius &&
              i_dot.y - mousePosition.y > -dots.d_radius
            ) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(i_dot.x, i_dot.y);
              ctx.lineTo(j_dot.x, j_dot.y);

              // make the fill colour fade out the further you are from the mouse
              const dotDistance =
                ((i_dot.x - mousePosition.x) ** 2 +
                  (i_dot.y - mousePosition.y) ** 2) **
                0.5;
              let distanceRatio = dotDistance / dots.d_radius;

              // make it so it doesnt fade out completely
              distanceRatio -= 0.3;
              if (distanceRatio < 0) {
                distanceRatio = 0;
              }

              ctx.strokeStyle = `rgb(81, 162, 233, ${1 - distanceRatio})`;

              ctx.stroke();
              ctx.closePath();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  };

  function createDots() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (let i = 0; i < dots.nb; i++) {
      dots.array.push(new Dot());
      var dot = dots.array[i];

      dot.create();
    }

    // first dot to be relativley large
    dots.array[0].radius = 1.5;

    // first dot to be blue
    dots.array[0].colour = '#51a2e9';

    // dot.line();
    dot.animate();
  }

  // window.onmousemove = function (parameter) {
  //   mousePosition.x = parameter.pageX;
  //   mousePosition.y = parameter.pageY;

  //   // sometimes if the mouse is off screen on refresh, it bugs out
  //   try {
  //     // want the first dot to follow the mouse
  //     dots.array[0].x = parameter.pageX;
  //     dots.array[0].y = parameter.pageY;
  //   } catch {
  //     //
  //   }
  // };

  window.onscroll = function (parameter) {
    mousePosition.x = window.innerWidth / 2;
    mousePosition.y = window.innerHeight / 2;

    const top =
      (window.pageYOffset || document.scrollTop) - (document.clientTop || 0);
    mousePosition.y += top;
    // console.log(top);

    // console.log(mousePosition.x);
  };

  // mousePosition.x = window.innerWidth / 2;
  // mousePosition.y = window.innerHeight / 2;

  const draw = setInterval(createDots, 1000 / 30);

  window.onresize = function () {
    clearInterval(draw);
    canvasDotsBg();

    // console.log('yoza');
  };
};

export default canvasDotsBg;
```

```css
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

header {  
    animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
    
    background: #333;
    padding: 30px;
  }

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
    color:rgb(0, 255, 234);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: FoundrySterlingOT3W03-Bold,FoundrySterlingOT3W10-Bold,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    right: 0px;
}

a:hover {
    color: white;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    max-height: 82px;
}

.linkedin {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin-top: -7px;
}

.intro {
    margin-top: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

#kevin {
    color: rgb(0, 255, 234);
}

#resume {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 130px;
    font-size: large;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(0, 255, 234);
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 45px;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;

}

#resume:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    color:rgb(0, 255, 234);
}

.skills {
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    left: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    
}

li {
    margin: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

.about {
    margin-top: 800px;
    color: white;
    font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: center;
}

.contact {
    margin-top: 920px;
    color: white;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 450px;

}

#about-scroll {
    margin-top: 500px;
}

#contact-scroll {
    margin-top: 920px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bscottnz/portfolio-site/main/src/bgCanvas.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </head>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    
<header id="home">
    <nav position: fixed; class="navbar navbar-expand-xxl navbar-dark ";>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kward937"><img class="linkedin" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174857.png"></a>
      <a href=#top>Home</a>
      <a href=#skill-scroll>Skills</a>
      <a href=#about-scroll>About</a>
      <a href=#contact-scroll>Contact</a>
    </nav></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Portfolio.css">
<body>
  <div class="canvas">
  <canvas class="canvas-2" width="1903" height="937" style="display: block;">
  </div>
```

Comment: @Sercan I've noticed my posts keep getting edited for the code formatting. Is there a guide on here to do this correctly the first time? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you can read here how to ask a good question

Comment: Why are you exporting that ? Do you have that in separate file ? Did you call that function `canvasDotsBg()` ? I tried call it and its working ?

Comment: I have the source javascript in a script. Do I need to have it as a local source or can I pull it using the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I made this project when I was still studying, I don’t need it anymore, but I hope it will help you somehow

P.S: GL HF ^_^

```js
const menu_button = document.querySelector(".menu-button");
        const container = document.querySelector(".container");
        const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
        const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

        const Top = document.querySelector("html");
        const info = document.querySelector(".info-block");
        const more = document.querySelector(".more-block");
        const service = document.querySelector(".service-block");
        const contacts = document.querySelector(".footer");
        const bar = document.getElementById("indicator");

        menu_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            menu_button.classList.toggle("active");
            menu.classList.toggle("show-menu");
        });

        function toInfo(){
            info.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
        }

        function toMore(){
            more.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
        }

        function toServices(){
            service.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
        }

        function toContacts(){
            contacts.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
            var y = window.scrollY;
            if(y > 50){
                navbar.style.cssText = "height: 55px;";
                menu.style.cssText = "padding-top: 60px;";
                bar.style.cssText = "top: 55px;";
            }
            else{
                navbar.style.cssText = "height: 75px;";
                menu.style.cssText = "padding-top: 80px;";
                bar.style.cssText = "top: 75px;";
            }
        })

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
            var y = window.scrollY;
            if(y > 1600){
                service.style.cssText = "transform: translateX(0);opacity: 1;";
            }
            else{
                service.style.cssText = "transform: translateX(400px);opacity: 0;";
            }
        })

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
            var y = window.scrollY;
            if(y > 650){
                more.style.cssText = "transform: translateX(0);opacity: 1;";
            }
            else{
                more.style.cssText = "transform: translateX(-400px);opacity: 0;";
            }
        })

        window.onscroll = function() {
            var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
          var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
          var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
          bar.style.height = scrolled + "%";
        };
```

```css
*{
            font-family: consolas;
        }

        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin-top: 75px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            background-color: white);
        }

        .progress-bar{
            position: fixed;
        width: 5px;
        left: 0px;
        transition: .5s;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #008AFF, #00FFE7); 
        z-index: 999;
        animation: animate_bar 5s infinite linear;
        }

        @keyframes animate_bar{
            0%,100%{
                filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
            }
            50%{
                filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        .navbar{
            top: 0;
            width: 90%;
            height: 75px;
            display: flex;
            position: fixed;
            padding: 0 5%;
            transition: .5s;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 999;
            border-bottom: 4px solid black; 
        }

        .logo{
            font-size: 48px;
        }

        .logo-link{
            text-decoration-line: none;
            color: black;
        }

        .menu-button{
            position: fixed;
            width: 2rem;
            height: 2rem;
            right: 5%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 9;
        }

        .bar{
            width: 2rem;
            height: 1.5px;
            background-color: #000;
            transition: .5s;
        }

        .bar:before,
        .bar:after{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: inherit;
            height: inherit;
            background-color: #000;
            transition: .5s;
        }

        .bar:before{
            transform: translateY(-9px);
        }

        .bar:after{
            transform: translateY(9px);
        }

        .menu-button.active .bar{
            transform: rotate(360deg);
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .menu-button.active .bar:before{
            transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
        }

        .menu-button.active .bar:after{
            transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
        }

        .menu{
            position: fixed;
            width: 20%;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            padding-top: 75px;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            transition: .5s;
            background-color: #555;
            transform: translateX(100%);
            border-left: 2px solid #000;
        }

        .show-menu{
            transform: translateX(0);
        }

        .menu ul{
            list-style: none;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .menu-link{
            width: 100%;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 0.7rem 0 0.7rem 2rem;
            display: block;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            transition: 0.5s;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .menu-link:hover{
            border-color: red;
        }

        .container{
            position: relative;
            transition: .5s;
            width: 90%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .margin-right{
            transform: translateX(-15%);
            width: 65%;
        }

        .block{
            padding: 5rem;
            margin: 2rem 0;
            color: white;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .block > *{
            margin: 2rem;
        }

        .top-block{
            background-image: url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2639558.jpg");
            animation: anim_left .5s 1 linear;
        }

        @keyframes anim_left{
            0%{
                transform: translateX(-400px);
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }

        .info-block{
            background-image: url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2639574.jpg");
            animation: anim_right 1s 1 linear;
        }

        @keyframes anim_right{
            0%,50%{
                transform: translateX(400px);
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100%{
                transform: translateX(0);
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        .more-block{
            background-image: url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4695971.jpg");
            display: flex;
            transition: .5s;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(-400px);
        }

        .more-title{
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 46px;
            letter-spacing: .75rem;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .more-category-block{
            width: 260px;
            padding: 2rem;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            border: 2px solid white;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
        }

        .more-img{
            position: relative;
            width: 40%;
        }

        .service-block{
            background-image: url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5412909.jpg");
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            padding: 5rem 0;
            transition: .5s;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(-400px);
        }

        .service-title{
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 46px;
            letter-spacing: .75rem;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .service-category-block{
            width: 320px;
            margin: 1rem;
            border: 2px solid white;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
        }

        .pro:before{
            position: absolute;
            width: 5rem;
            height: 5rem;
            border: 2px solid white;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 50%;
            font-size: 26px;
            color: red;
            font-weight: 600;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 5rem;
        }

        .pro:before{
            content: "-25%";
            transform: translateX(270px) translateY(-340px) rotate(-7deg);
        }

        .service-list{
            list-style: none;
            line-height: 1.5;
        }

        .service-name{
            font-size: 24px;
            margin: 1rem;
        }

        .sub-service-name{
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .text-center{
            text-align: center;
        }

        .yes:before{
            content: "✔";
            position: absolute;
            transform: translateX(-1.4rem);
            color: green;
        }

        .no:before{
            content: "✘";
            position: absolute;
            transform: translateX(-1.4rem);
            color: red;
        }

        .price{
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        .btn{
            outline: none;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 1px solid white;
            color: white;
            padding: 1rem 2rem;
            font-size: 16px;
            transition: .5s;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 0 2rem;
        }

        .btn:hover{
            color: black;
            border-color: black;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .btn-center{
            margin: 1rem 5rem;
        }

        .footer{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
            background-image: url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4978922.jpg");
            background-position: center;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .contacts{
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 4rem;
        }

        .contact-list{
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            line-height: 1.75;
        }
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar" id="indicator"></div>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo"><a href="index.html" class="logo-link">Wolf Gym</a></div>
        <div class="menu-button">
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" class="menu-link">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-link" onclick="toInfo()">About us</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-link" onclick="toMore()">Why us</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-link" onclick="toServices()">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-link" onclick="toContacts()">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block top-block">
            <p>Welcome to the official "Wolf Gym" website.</p>
            <button class="btn" onclick="toServices()">View proposals</button>
        </div>

        <div class="block info-block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus saepe sed provident odio accusamus, molestias corrupti tenetur iste. Eligendi et, quo voluptates adipisci quam suscipit maiores eum dolor porro praesentium.</p>
            <p>Lorem :</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn" onclick="alert('Site-ul se afla in proces de creare!')">More</button>
        </div>

        <div class="block more-block">
            <p class="text-center more-title">Why us</p>
            <div class="more-category-block">
                <img src="experience.png" class="more-img">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing, elit. Reiciendis necessitatibus quos unde. Illo ut maxime laudantium maiores numquam totam natus vitae voluptate, ducimus dolorem facere consectetur mollitia porro temporibus repudiandae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="more-category-block">
                <img src="muscle.png" class="more-img">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing, elit. Reiciendis necessitatibus quos unde. Illo ut maxime laudantium maiores numquam totam natus vitae voluptate, ducimus dolorem facere consectetur mollitia porro temporibus repudiandae.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="more-category-block">
                <img src="growth.png" class="more-img">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing, elit. Reiciendis necessitatibus quos unde. Illo ut maxime laudantium maiores numquam totam natus vitae voluptate, ducimus dolorem facere consectetur mollitia porro temporibus repudiandae.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="more-category-block">
                <img src="muscle1.png" class="more-img">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing, elit. Reiciendis necessitatibus quos unde. Illo ut maxime laudantium maiores numquam totam natus vitae voluptate, ducimus dolorem facere consectetur mollitia porro temporibus repudiandae.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="block service-block basic">
            <p class="text-center service-title">Our offers</p>
            <div class="service-category-block">
                <p class="text-center service-name">Basic (30 days)</p>
                <p class="text-center sub-service-name">This service includes :</p>
                <ul class="service-list">
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="no">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                    <li class="no">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                    <li class="no">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                    <li class="no">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
                </ul>
                <p class="price text-center">200 mdl</p>
                <button class="btn btn-center" onclick="alert('Site-ul se afla in proces de creare!')">Buy</button>
            </div>

            <div class="service-category-block pro">
                <p class="text-center service-name">Pro (365 days)</p>
                <p class="text-center sub-service-name">This service includes :</p>
                <ul class="service-list">
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li class="yes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                </ul>
                <p class="price text-center">6 500 mdl</p>
                <button class="btn btn-center" onclick="alert('Site-ul se afla in proces de creare!')">Buy</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="contacts">Contacte</div>
        <ul class="contact-list">
            <li>Adresa de email : wolf@gym.com</li>
            <li>Tel. : +373 555 22 555</li>
            <li>Fix : 022 555 222</li>
            <li>Physiz addresses : 3370  Henry Ford Avenue</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```